# Why are notes in latex-beamer not working?

Tags: beamer, incompatibility

I want to use the note-functionality of latex-beamer which should, according to the [user guide](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), work as follow: I add a `\note{Sometext}` somewhere on a slide and if I now switch on the notes-printing using the `show notes` option, another slide should be inserted after the current one, containing the node "Sometext".

This doesn't work for me: The notes are always shown like this: 
[image: Wrong display]

This is not what I expected and not what the documentation states. In fact, the notes printing can not be disabled if replacing the `show notes` with `hide notes`. They are always printed, but not on their own page.

See this minimal working example which generates the presentation above.

```
\documentclass[18pt]{beamer}

% Many imports
\usepackage{mdwlist}
% More imports

\usetheme{Warsaw}    
\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Eggs
    \item Plants
    \item Animals \note{Animals are quite huge}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It took me hours to find this bug, for this reason I'm publishing it here.

Comment: Well, I can not answer the question 'Why are the notes not working when using the mdwlist package', I simply don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem results from including the `mdwlist` package in my presentation. **When removing this package `mdwlist` import, everything works like expected:**

[image: Correct Presentation]

The mdwlist package is very incompatible with latex-beamer: When including another item in the list like this:

```
\item<2> Animals \note<2>{Animals are quite huge}
```

The inclusion of `mdwlist` leads to the following (very strange) error, which has nothing to do with the mdwlist package:

```
./test.tex:15: LaTeX Error: \begin{altenv} on input line 15 ended by \end{itemize}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \end{frame}


./test.tex:15: LaTeX Error: \begin{uncoverenv} on input line 15 ended by \end{beamer@framepauses}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \end{frame}

./test.tex:15: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endbeamer@frameslide ...amer@framepauses}\egroup 
                                                  \ifx \beamer@frametitle \@...
l.15 \end{frame}


./test.tex:15: LaTeX Error: \begin{actionenv} on input line 15 ended by \end{beamer@frameslide}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \end{frame}


./test.tex:17: LaTeX Error: \begin{itemize} on input line 15 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17 \end{document}

(/home/dominik/Documents/Diplomarbeit/presentation/build/test.aux)
./test.tex:17: You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
\enddocument ... \endgroup \deadcycles \z@ \@@end 

l.17 \end{document}


./test.tex:17: LaTeX Error: \begin{itemize} on input line 15 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.17 \end{document}

)
! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex
```