# Beamer notes on secondary screen doesn't work

Tags: beamer, pdf, notes, pgfpages

I am writing a presentation for at introduction to latex and think it would be nice to show how I have my presentation-notes on my laptop screen (Macbook Air) using Beamer.
But it just won't work.

This minimal example taken straight from the manual has no effect:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Note test}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item<1-> Eggs
       \item<2-> Plants
         \note[item]<2>{Tell joke about plants.}
         \note[item]<2>{Make it short.}
       \item<3-> Animals
       \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have tried in the following viewers: Adobe Reader 11, Apple Preview, Skim and SplitShow (mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/in-beamer-slide-view-notes-on-computer-only-while-presenting-with-a-projector)). 
I am quite sure my graphic card supports two screen mode, since I am currently writing this text on an external monitor while my laptop holds other screen contents (MacBook Air).
When I run the file I only get a regular slideshow with the expected slides, but no indication of secondary slides with notes. There is something strange with the pagenumbering though: The viewer notes slide 1-2 as page one and getting to the third slide it writes page: 4. So I have a feeling the note slide is there somewhere, but I can't get it to show.

The suggestions mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110786/beamer-notes-show-notes-on-second-screen-option-does-not-work) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73046/why-are-notes-in-latex-beamer-not-working) either don't apply or don't work.

I have tried compiling the document in TexShop as well as Aquamacs.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: @Stenskjaer: I have no problem whith two screens. I use two monitors and enlarged the adobe reader view too be on both monitors. Then I have on the right the notes: http://perce.de/pub/screen.jpg

Comment: @Herbert: That's what frustrates me so, because though it seems to be so simple, it just won't seem to work...

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Thanks, I'm happy to be here! Next time I'll try to comply as well as possible with the general code of conduct.

Comment: @Herbert, So that involves configuring the display as one virtual screen stretched across two physical screens and then putting the notes in the area picked up by one monitor and the slides in the area picked up by the other? As I understood it, though, Beamer is supposed to support putting the notes on a separate virtual screen (corresponding to a separate physical monitor) semi-automatically, and I thought that was the question here? Does your solution work when using full screen mode for the slides?

Comment: I´m getting errors running the MWE provided. Anyway, on the beamer manual (p. 211) we have " Not all presentation programs support this special feature. For example, the Acrobat Reader
 6.0.2 will only use one screen in fullscreen mode on MacOS X. On the other hand, a program named PDF Presenter supports showing dual-screen presentations. Generally, you will have to find out for yourself whether your display program and system support showing superwide presentations stretching over two screens."

So, try use the software mentioned on the manual: http://pdfpresenter.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue with the viewer/PC, not with LaTeX.

Comment: This one is borderline but I think OT: `beamer` is generating the correct PDF so the problem is at the viewer/PC end and that can't be solved using TeX knowledge.